# _initAutoloader database name same as class

Tags: zend-framework, autoloader

I am new at Zend and i am learning.
I am getting the following error:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cddb.model_dbtable_albums' doesn't exist
```

But the test tablename is albums in the database, if i change it to model_dbtable_albums it works.
I just want to name the table like albums and not the classname.

What do i do wrong ;-)

This is the bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap{
    protected function _initAutoload(){
    $moduleloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
    'namespace'=> '',  
    'basePath'=> APPLICATION_PATH));
```

indexAction controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $albums = new Model_DbTable_Albums();
    $this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Please show your application.ini file.

Comment: Bas, it might be worth learning ZF2 rather than ZF1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your model `Model_DbTable_Albums` extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` set:

```
protected $_name = 'albums';
```

See the [Zend_Db_table docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html).

Comment: protected $_name = 'albums'; Works!